# How to play a audio like spotify premium while the user is playing a song

Tags: html

I know this sounds stupid but i am new to this and get stared with html. I am creating a streaming website and i want to monetize it. Is there a way to randomly advertise it like spotify premium. I have already created the sound tracks for the audio which i want to play. Hope somebody helps me. Thank You

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. I understand you're just getting started with HTML so I highly recommend you begin with something much simpler because this requires a lot more than just understanding HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your question involves much more than just learning basic HTML, however if I understand it correctly I would implement the following logic to "randomly advertise":

1. Create a login feature for your application that separates premium from non-premium users
2. When playing audio for a user, create a function that identifies if the user is in fact in the premium tier and, based on the result, either:

a) If the user is not in the premium tier, play your advertising audio tracks after every other track

b) If the user is in the premium tier, play songs without advertisements in between them

Hope this helps, but keep in mind that your question should be way more specific in order for the answers to be helpful for actual issues regarding your code or implementation.